# How do I align faces exactly to an axis?

Tags: snapping, axis

I have several objects that are pieces harvested from larger models, and I can't get those pieces to align with other objects.  This is for 3D printing, so I need to be able to make faces perfectly flat.  Here's an example:

[image]

The blue and red objects need to line up perfectly to form a single congruent surface, but no matter what I've tried, I can't get them to line up.  I've tried to follow advice on snapping, but it doesn't seem to work.  I've also seen where people were advised to use scaling to accomplish this, but that changes the geometry of the object.

I need to be able to select the top faces of the red object and make them perfectly flush with the global x-axis, without changing the geometry--basically, just automatically rotating the object so that it lines up with the axis.  How do I do this?

Comment: Maybe [Transform Quantizer](https://blenderartists.org/t/transform-quantizer/1403707) addon can help

Comment: I'm checking it out, but it's not clear how to use this to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "Align and Distribute" Addon created by Amandeep, you can get it on his [gumroad](https://amanbairwal.gumroad.com/l/AlignAndDistribute) page.

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was so simple.  I can't believe how much time and effort that saved me.  Thanks!